# Find $f$ and $g$ such that $\Phi(x)f(y)=g(x+y)$

Tags: calculus, functions, normal-distribution

Let $\Phi: \mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$ define the standard normal cdf function. I am trying to find some functions $f$ and $g$ -- if they exist -- such that $$\Phi(x)f(y)=g(x+y)$$ for all $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$. I don't care about an explicit form for $g$, but would like to find some $f$ so that the above holds.

Any hint regarding the existence of such $f$ and $g$ or the form of $f$ would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible. If the condition
$$\Phi(x)f(y)=g(x+y)\tag1$$
holds for all $x,y$, then taking $x=-y$ yields 
$$f(y)={g(0)\over \Phi(-y)}={c\over 1-\Phi(y)}$$
as the explicit form for $f$ (with $c$ a constant). Plugging this into (1), we find that
$${c\Phi(x) \over 1-\Phi(y)}=g(x+y)$$
cannot hold for any $g$: The value of the LHS when $(x,y)=(1,0)$ is different from the value when $(x,y)=(0,1)$, but the RHS is $g(1)$ in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Take derivatives with respect to $y$ and with respect to $x$. Subtract the resulting equations. You obtain 
$$
\phi'(x)f(y)-\phi(x)f'(y)=0\\
\Leftrightarrow \frac{d}{dx}\ln(\phi(x))=\frac{d}{dy}\ln(f(y))
$$
Conclude that both sides must be constant. But the left-hand side isn't

Comment: That should imply one should be a constant multiple of the other,isn't it?

Comment: the last equation in my answer shows that $\frac{d}{dx} \ln(\phi(x))=\frac{d}{dy}\ln(f(y))=a$ would need to hold, i.e. $\phi(x)=\exp(ax+b)$ and  $f(y)=\exp(ay+c)$ if that's what you mean.

Comment: Clever! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

If that functional equation is to be true for all $(x,y)$, then in particular it should hold identically along the $x$- and $y$-axes. If $y=0$, then $\Phi(x)f(0)=g(x)$ for all $x$; if $x=0$, then $\Phi(0)f(y)=g(y)$ for all $y$. Between these, we conclude $f(x)=\dfrac{f(0)}{\Phi(0)}\Phi(x)$ for all $x$ i.e. $f(x)\propto \Phi(x)$. But then $\Phi(x)f(y)\propto \Phi(x)\Phi(y)$, which is not a function of $x+y$.